# The "X" property on "Y" could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

When I run my application and I click a specific button I get the error:

```
"The "X" property on "Y" could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'."
```

Cool so I go to my Entity project, go to Y table, find X column, right-click and go to X's properties and find that Nullable is set to False.

I verify in SQL that in Y table, X is set to allow nulls, and it is.

I then go back to my Entity project, set Nullable to True, save and build and I receive:

```
Error 3031: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 4049:Non-nullable column "X" in table "Y" is mapped to a nullable entity property.
```

I've heard that deleting the table from the .edmx file and then re-adding it is a possibility but have never done that and don't understand the implications enough to feel comfortable in doing that.

I've heard that it could be in the view, could be in the stored procedure...

Also have heard that this is a bug.

Has anyone come across this and found an "across the board" fix or somewhat of a road map of sorts on where to look for this error?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you actually tried?  I don't know what the .edmx file is, but you could simply try deleting/re-adding it as suggested.  If that doesn't work out, replace with your original.  You _are_ using a VCS (version control system) of some sort, right?

Comment: Did you update your objects after changing the entity? You probably have X property in Y object still defined as 'int' instead of 'int?'

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
 "The "X" property on "Y" could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'."
```

In your EDMX, if you go under your Y table and click on X column, right-click, click on Properties, scroll down to `Nullable` and change from `False` to `True`.

If you get a "mapping fragment" error, you'll have to delete the table from the EDMX and re-add it, because in the Model Browser it stores the table properties and the only way to refresh that (that I know of) is to delete the table from the Model Browser under `<database>.Store` then retrieving it using `Update Model from Database..` command.

Answer (score 30):

I just replace data type `int` to `int32?`

```
public Int32 Field{ get; set; }
```

to

```
public Int32? Field{ get; set; }
```

and the problem is solved

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks for saving me a ton of time! However I would like to point out that this works for "int" as well. Here is my code: `public int? Success { get; set; }`

Comment: This is the best non-obvious answer.  I haven't even tried it yet and I'm pretty sure this is my problem.

Comment: Unable to edit my answer.  Yes, changing to a nullable type did fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that my Model database was out of sync with the actual (dev) database. So the EDMX thought it was `smallint` but the actual column was int. I updated the model database to `int` and the EDMX to `Int32` and now it works.

Comment: (Using MVC)  Field was defined as Small Int in the DB, but as Int in the Model.  Changed the def in the model to Int16.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

For future readers.

I got this error when I had a multiple result stored procedure.

As seen here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx

If you try to access an item in the first-result, after doing a `.NextResult`, you may get this error.

From the article:

```
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    // Read Blogs from the first result set
    var blogs = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
        .ObjectContext
        .Translate<Blog>(reader, "Blogs", MergeOption.AppendOnly);   


    foreach (var item in blogs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }        

    // Move to second result set and read Posts
    reader.NextResult();
    var posts = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
        .ObjectContext
        .Translate<Post>(reader, "Posts", MergeOption.AppendOnly);


    foreach (var item in posts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
    }
```

Now, if **before** the line

```
foreach (var item in posts)
```

you put in this code

```
Blog foundBlog = blogs.FirstOrDefault();
```

I think you can simulate the error.

Rule of Thumb:

You still gotta treat this thing like a `DataReader` (fire-hose).

For my needs, I had to convert to a `List<>`.

So I changed this:

```
    foreach (var item in blogs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }
```

to this:

```
    List<Blog> blogsList = blogs.ToList();
    foreach (var item in blogsList )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }
```

And I was able to navigate the objects without getting the error.

Here is another way I encountered it.

```
    private void DoSomething(ObjectResult<Blog> blogs, ObjectResult<Post> posts)
    {

    }
```

And then after this code (in the original sample)

```
foreach (var item in posts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
}
```

put in this code:

```
DoSomething(blogs,posts);
```

If I called that routine and started accessing items/properties in the blogs and posts, I would encounter the issue.  I understand why, I should have caught it the first time.

Comment: I had a stored proc that returned multiple sets and I found if I cast the field as the correct type, it took care of this issue. If it's a 0, the DB will assume it's an int and not a bit. As everything is hard cast, it stops being an issue once you cast any fields that might be cast incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I verified that the entity was pointing at the correct database.

I then deleted the table from the .edmx file and added it again.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Check your model & database both should be defined accordingly....

public Int32? X { get; set; } ----> Nullable
Accordingly in DB 'X' should be Nullable = True

or

public Int32 X { get; set; } ----> not Nullable
Accordingly in DB 'X' should be Nullable = false

Answer (score 1):

In my case in created view in DB column that I select that contains null value  I change  that value by this select statement:

Before my change

```
 select 
     ..., GroupUuId , ..
```

after my change

```
 select 
     ..., ISNULL(GroupUuId, 0), ...
```

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

This may happen when the database table allows NULL and there are records that have a null value and you try to read this record with EF and the mapping class does not allow a null value.

The solution is either change the database table so that it does not allow null or change your class to allow null.

Answer (score 1):

For me the following Steps corrected the Error:

1. Remove the 'X'-Property from the 'Y'-Table
2. Save EDMX
3. build Database from Model
4. compile
5. Add the 'X'-Property to 'Y'-Table again (with non-nullable and int16)
6. Save EDMX
7. build Database from Model
8. compile

Answer (score 0):

to fix the error

```
 Error 3031: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 4049:Non-nullable column "X" in table "Y" is mapped to a nullable entity property.
```

open your EDMX file with and xml editor and lookup you table in

> edmx:StorageModels

find the propertie which gives the error and set or add

> Nullable="false" >> to  Nullable="true"

save the edmx, open it in visual studio and build it. problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Got same error but different context, tried to join tables using linq where for one of the tables in database, a non-null column had a null value inserted, updated the value to default and the issue is fixed.

Comment: A non-null column can't possibly have "a null value inserted". Also, this doesn't answer the original question, is it really helpful to post this?

Comment: Actually, it can Gert, if the table definition has been updated with No Check.

Comment: @GertArnold, As ARLibertarian answered there is a possibility of a non-null column to have a null. And as clearly mentioned the context is different but issue is similar. Hoping it will help someone save time. My learning, legacy DB data design faults.